# host dns lookup curiosity

Tags: domain-name-system, host, dig

Can anyone help me understand this :--

```
%)-- host brahma.mksh.net      
Host brahma.mksh.net not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

now when I run dig with trace.. I get the A record for brahma.mksh.net that I've assigned..

```
%)-- dig brahma.mksh.net +trace

; <<>> DiG 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-4.P1.el5 <<>> brahma.mksh.net +trace
;; global options:  printcmd
.                       453157  IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.                       453157  IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       453157  IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       453157  IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.                       453157  IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       453157  IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.                       453157  IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       453157  IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
.                       453157  IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.                       453157  IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
.                       453157  IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       453157  IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.                       453157  IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
;; Received 512 bytes from 216.145.54.95#53(216.145.54.95) in 1 ms

net.                    172800  IN      NS      k.gtld-servers.net.
net.                    172800  IN      NS      b.gtld-servers.net.
net.                    172800  IN      NS      i.gtld-servers.net.
net.                    172800  IN      NS      f.gtld-servers.net.
net.                    172800  IN      NS      l.gtld-servers.net.
net.                    172800  IN      NS      h.gtld-servers.net.
net.                    172800  IN      NS      j.gtld-servers.net.
net.                    172800  IN      NS      g.gtld-servers.net.
net.                    172800  IN      NS      a.gtld-servers.net.
net.                    172800  IN      NS      d.gtld-servers.net.
net.                    172800  IN      NS      c.gtld-servers.net.
net.                    172800  IN      NS      m.gtld-servers.net.
net.                    172800  IN      NS      e.gtld-servers.net.
;; Received 490 bytes from 192.228.79.201#53(b.root-servers.net) in 74 ms

mksh.net.               172800  IN      NS      ns16.zoneedit.com.
mksh.net.               172800  IN      NS      ns17.zoneedit.com.
;; Received 115 bytes from 192.52.178.30#53(k.gtld-servers.net) in 176 ms

brahma.mksh.net.        300     IN      A       71.198.58.88
mksh.net.               7200    IN      NS      ns16.zoneedit.com.
mksh.net.               7200    IN      NS      ns17.zoneedit.com.
;; Received 99 bytes from 69.64.68.41#53(ns16.zoneedit.com) in 37 ms
```

Is my DNS misconfigured? 
what gives?

Answer (score 4):

Name's resolving just fine.  Something's cached in your host's DNS or its resolver giving you that `NXDOMAIN` - give it some time, but it's working just fine from Google's DNS servers.

Comment: And you can flush your local dns (linux) by bring down your interface and then bring it up.